# Using "fscanf" in C How can Split two strings?

Tags: c, list, linked-list, scanf, strtok

I want to a linked list in C using file operations. I want to get a line and split it and storage in structers. But I cant split two strings.

My File like this:

> 1#Emre#Dogan
> 2#John#Smith
> 3#Ashley#Thomas
> etc...

I want to read one line from file using fscanf.

```
fscanf(file,"%d#%s#%s",&number,name,surmane);
```

But the result is

> Number : 1
> Name : Emre#Dogan

How can get rid of that # element in the name and split it to name and surname;

Comment: Try using strtok() to parse the input string

Comment: you can also use sscanf() function. for detailed example go here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("Input.txt", "r");

    int number;
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    char line_data[1024];

    fgets(line_data, 1024, fptr);

    number = atoi(strtok(line_data, "#"));
    name = strtok(NULL, "#");
    surname = strtok(NULL, "#");    

    printf("%d %s %s", number, name, surname);
}
```

Output:

```
1 Emre Dogan
```

EDIT:
Coverted the variable "number" from string to integer.

Comment: But this program still show me only the last name and number.. And splitted it.  Number : 1 Emre DOGAN 2 Emre GAN 3 Emre N 4 Emre DOGN etc..

Comment: @EmreDoğan Above program reads only single line from the input file pointer. You have to write a loop to read all the lines and then process it accordingly using strtok. I suggest you to read the man page for fgets and strtok before you start updating your program. In case if you find any difficulty in implementing your idea, you can post it here along with code sample and I'm always ready to help you!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to read a full line using `fgets()`, then parsing that line. This is more robust, using `fscanf()` directly on the input stream can be confusing due to the way `fscanf()` skips whitespace.

So, you could do:

```
char line[1024];

if(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
{
  int age;
  char name[256], surname[256];

  if(sscanf(line, "%d#%255[^#]#%255s", &age, name, surname) == 3)
  {
    printf("it seems %s %s is %d years old\n", name, surname, age);
  }
}
```

This uses the `%[]` format specifier to avoid including the `#` separator in the parsed strings. I think this is cleaner than `strtok()`, which is a scary function best avoided.